# Converting JS RegEx To PHP Not Working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I had this JS/jQuery:

```
$(this).text().replace(/([^\s]+)/, day);
```

which took a line like `MAR/26/2013 05:00 PM` and converted it to `05:00 PM`.

But this PHP does not do a proper replacement for some reason:

```
$time = preg_replace('/([^\s]+)/', '', $dateStr);
```

Instead I am left with a string containing one space.

I converted all of my code flawlessly up until the aforementioned line. `$(this).text()` has the same value as `$dateStr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$dateStr` will always be in that format and you only want the 5:00pm component, try:

```
$dateStr= "MAR/26/2013 05:00 PM";
$time = explode(" ", $dateStr);
echo $time[1]." ".$time[2];
```